# When registering scroll event in Jquery's animate callback it gets sometimes triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created simple example. I have a code where I register scroll event to window after the animation is completed, but you can see in console that the scroll event is triggered 1-2 times and I believe it shouldn't unless I really start to scroll.
I tried google search but without success. There was one post where css transition was affecting it somehow, but you can see there is no transitions in my case.

```js
function done() {
 $(window).on('scroll.c', function() {
   console.log('scrolled');
  });
}

function scrollTo(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  $(window).off('scroll.c');
 $('html, body').animate({
   'scrollTop': $('#to').offset().top 
  }, 200, done);
}

$('#link').on('click', scrollTo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link">XXX</a>

<div style="height: 2000px; background: silver;">

</div>

<section id="to">
  <h1>XXX</h1>
</section>

<div style="height: 2000px; background: silver;">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delaying the re-registration of the event by 50ms seems to sort it out:

```js
function done() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(window).on('scroll.c', function() {
      console.log('scrolled');
    });
  }, 10);
}

function scrollTo(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  var gotDone = false;
  $(window).off('scroll.c');
 $('html, body').animate({
   'scrollTop': $('#to').offset().top 
  }, 200, function() {
    if (!gotDone) {
      gotDone = true;
      done();
    }
  });
}

$('#link').on('click', scrollTo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link">XXX</a>

<div style="height: 2000px; background: silver;">

</div>

<section id="to">
  <h1>XXX</h1>
</section>

<div style="height: 2000px; background: silver;">

</div>
```

I expected just a 0ms timeout would do it on the theory the scroll events had been queued but not yet processed, but it didn't. 10ms seems to on Chrome, but Firefox wanted 50ms (as it seems to for a few things like this).

Comment: I guessed timeout would do it, but I find timeout solutions lame, am I wrong?

Comment: anyway I already spend too much time on this nonsense, I'll just use the timeout. I was wondering if there isn't better solution. Thanks.

Comment: @user8672473: Sometimes they are, other times they're just fine (in particular, using `setTimeout(..., 0)` to set up something to run on the next pass of the event loop is just fine). Ones like the above are absolutely a last resort. But when the 0ms didn't work (e.g., not just a matter of scheduling for the next loop), I couldn't think of anything else we could respond to (other than the first scroll event). BTW, I've updated the snippet: Your `done` would get called **twice** with your original code, because the callback is per-element.